# When is it necessary to have visual feedback if auditory feedback is primary?

Tags: feedback, audio, audio-interface

Example: If a product's main feedback is auditory (ie. alarm clock, voice assistant) when is it necessary to give visual feedback (ie. LED indicator, display graphic)?

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry if I misunderstand the question, but I've been given little detail.*

I would say **always**, because:

1. People can have their sound turned off, because of their location or they forgot to turn it on.
2. Some people are deaf and will never be able to hear the feedback.

You could also have a clear toggle button in your application or website to turn visual feedback on/off.

Comment: Or, for (1), just because they don't like noisy devices! My phone normally only sounds for incoming calls, _some_ notifications and the alarm clock. My PC is usually silent (unless on Skype, and then I use headphones) and in the past, portable games machines (Sony PSP, Nintendo SP and DS) were nearly always played with the sound off.